# Localhost is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, internet-explorer-11

I have an ASP.NET web application project that I am trying to launch in Internet Explorer 11 (either Debug > Start Debugging or Debug > Start Without Debugging). I am getting an error popup that says "Unable to start program 'http://localhost:52528/. http://localhost:52528/ is not a valid Win32 application". Did some research online and found a older blog post suggesting to launch 32-bit Internet Explorer instead of 64-bit. However, I couldn't figure out how to do it on Windows 10.
The issue doesn't seem to be limited to Visual Studio 2017 - I saw the same behavior with VS 2015.
[image]

Comment: If you look at the Project Properties > Debug tab. What does it say there?

Comment: run your VS as admin.

Comment: @rene ASP.NET projects don't have a Debug tab in properties.

Comment: @Steve Yes, I am running VS as admin

Comment: looks like you're using the wrong IE ... look at this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows_10/can-windows-10-run-a-32-bit-internet-explorer/bc658cd9-3061-4e2c-9e50-bd047181de06